# Ruby on Rails - Order by count of related table records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to do a query and cannot seem to crack the syntax of this.  So I need to grab surveys for the current month, most recent, limit it to 5, and then order by the count of the related table which is the responses for the survey.  So if a survey has had 8 responses and another 4, the one with 8 will show up at the top.

I have a scope set to find surveys for the month, but either I need to ditch that for a more involved query, or find a way to order it by the max `survey.response_count` .

This is the closest I have gotten but is still not correct.

```
@sorted_active_surveys = Survey.joins(:survey_responses).group(:survey_id).order('COUNT(survey_responses.survey_id) DESC')
```

If I try in combination with the scope the `created_at` date becomes ambiguous and errors out.

Survey.rb

```
scope :for_month, ->(date) { where("MONTH(created_at) = ?", date.month).limit(5) }
```

This also creates the same error

```
    scope :for_month, ->(date) { where("MONTH(survey.created_at) = ?", date.month).limit(5) }
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: In your last code sample I believe you want to say `surveys.created_at` instead of `survey.created_at`. This might not be your problem but I wanted to point it out.

Comment: You are right, I needed to use plurals in there.  I don't write a lot of queries like this so trying to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't keep the scope but seems to order by response count correctly and keep the dates within the current month.

```
Survey.where('surveys.created_at > ? AND surveys.created_at < ?', Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month).joins(:survey_responses).group(:survey_id).order('COUNT(survey_responses.survey_id) DESC')
```